# Customize Node Names in Ruby's Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, builder

I'm building a tool that generates dynamic xml.  As a result my Models have pretty generic names:

```
Project 
  has_many    :Groups

Group
  has_many    :Items
  has_many    :Groups
  belongs_to  :Project

Item
  has_many    :Params
  belongs_to  :Group

Param
  belongs_to  :Project
  belongs_to  :Group
  belongs_to  :Item
```

So when I build the xml from the project controller, the project node name is the root node of the xml.  But I don't want it called "project".  I want the node to be whatever the @project.params['name'] value is.

The problem I'm having is that the structure of builder is making this difficult... When I do:

```
xml.project do
  ~some code
end
```

...It's always going to create "project" as the root node name.  I can't find a way to override it to use a different name.  I was hoping something like the following would work:

```
xml.send(@project.params.name) {
  ...some code
}
```

..but that obviously isn't working.  So I'm essentially trying to find a way to alias the element names that are configured in my params model.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of doing xml.project, try:

```
xml.tag! @project.params.name do
```

That should also be used if there is a hyphen in the element name.

Comment: I just figured this out too.  Thanks for the response!